# asp.net core & Angular & catchError: How to provide custom message via IActionResult?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I am returning a custom error message as an ActionResult from asp.net core like so:

```
return NotFound(new { message = "Document file doesn't exist" });
```

But I don't see how to get the message from catchError within an angular interceptor:

```
intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(this.updateHeader(request)).pipe(
      catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {

        // Try to refresh token or logout in case refresh wasn't successful
        if (err.status === 401) { ... }
...
```

The err objects looks like this:

```
error: Blob { size: 61, type: "application/json" }
​headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: lazyInit() }
​message: "Http failure response for https://localhost:44357/api/documents/1121: 404 Not Found"
​name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​ok: false
​status: 404
​statusText: "Not Found"
​url: "https://localhost:44357/api/documents/1121"
​<prototype>: Object { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that err.error is a Blob when the request expects a blob response, this seems to be an Angular bug. So the solution is to read the blob and parse the contained JSON. Something like

```
if (err.error instanceof Blob) {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener('loadend', (e) => {
        let result = e.srcElement['result'];
        let resultObject = JSON.parse(result);
        let errMsg = resultObject.message;
        this.translate
            .get(errMsg)
            .subscribe(text => this.toastr.error(text));
    });
    reader.readAsText(err.error);
```

[How to handle error for response Type blob in HttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48500822/how-to-handle-error-for-response-type-blob-in-httprequest)